# Set TextBlock text in style setter value in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to change text of TextBlock x:name="TxtRect" in runtime which comes from style resource file. I'm trying to get a TextBlock element in code behind and edit its value in runtime. Then to get and change the text by my code but it doesn't change in running project.

This is my usercontrol1.xaml

```
     <Grid>            

            <Button Name="Btn1" Content="btn1"
                ToolTip="{Binding DisplayName}"/>


            <Button  Name="Btn2" Content="btn2"
                ToolTip="{Binding DisplayName}" />

     </Grid>
```

This is my resource in Styles.xaml

```
    <Style x:Key="TileButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF363636"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="170"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="235"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                   Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                   StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding 
                        BorderThickness}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TxtRect" Text="Hi there" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Foreground="#FFF"
                                   Margin="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
```

And here I have my usercontrol1.cs

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myStyle = TryFindResource("TileButtonStyle") as Style;

         if (myStyle != null)
        {
            foreach (var s in myStyle.Setters)
            {
                if (((Setter)s).Property.ToString().Equals("Template"))
                {
                    var franworkTemplate = (FrameworkTemplate)((Setter)s).Value;
                    var txtBlock = franworkTemplate.LoadContent().FindChildren<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "TxtRect");

                    if (txtBlock == null) continue;
                    txtBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "dsafasfs"); //this is not working at all
                    txtBlock.Text = "NewText"; // this works but in debuging mode and not change text value in runtime for view xaml page
                }
            }

            Btn1.SetValue(Control.StyleProperty, myStyle);
            Btn2.SetValue(Control.StyleProperty, myStyle);
        }
    }
```

This is my actual Button which I am using:

```
   <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type}">
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource TileButtonStyle}" Content="{StaticResource UserFigure}" x:Name="Btn1"
                    ToolTip="{Binding DisplayName}" Command="{Binding DataContext.GoToCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding RegisteredName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the right way to do it. What do you actually want to solve with that? There are probably better options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because directly assigned `Content` have higher priority than style setter, so Content will override you'r code behind text of setter.

**Edit** 
Actualy that's more complex, but h/e you can achive this with below code

Instead of this, you can use template binidng to `Content` property of button, like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TxtRect" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Foreground="#FFF"
                                   Margin="5"/>
```

Then you just change it at runtime like this:

```
Btn1.Content = "Hi there"
```

Comment: I really appreciate you to answer but after trying to my code is not working.

Comment: What exactly happens?

Comment: You can always do the trick with templateBinding to Tag, and setting tag as text, if not you can create your custom button with new dependency property (e.g. Text) and textbox text to that property

Comment: I have added my Button control to end of my question in this page and as you can see that is located inside of DataTemplate first and Content has own value.

Comment: Change to tag property instead :P

Comment: I do not how can I explain my happiness. Many thanks.That is working to me.

Comment: One more thing, do you really need to set content same as name?

Comment: Well, I'm happy with you too than :)

Comment: Yeah, I need to use content as name.